# How do I check if passwords match in storyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, xcode-storyboard

I am basically making a login page, and want to make sure that passwords match before I can enable the continue button. I looked at the storyboard intro on the Apple website, but I didn't really understand exactly how I can link my storyboard to code and check if the passwords match.

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: You're asking about two things that are only vaguely related.  Storyboards are for designing and implementing a user interface.  They have no direct connection to security.  (You can create a text field and compare what a user types to whatever you want by using a UITextFieldDelegate.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't, exactly. In your storyboard you'd connect the various fields in your user interface to IBOutlets (for connecting things, the nouns of your UX) and IBActions (for responding to user actions, the verbs) to your view controller.

Fields like UItextField also can have a "delegate", an object that helps them manage their behavior. You'd hook up your view controller as a delegate of both of your password input fields, and when the passwords don't match, the view controller logic would disable the continue button.

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess I was just unclear on how y UI would work with code.

Comment: What I said in my answer is a short summary of how UI works with code. When the user interacts with the UI, it invokes code you write, usually in your view controller. The code can be invoked by IBAction links, or by invoking the delegate methods of certain types of UI components. Also look at `UIGetstureRecognizer` objects. Those let you detect and respond to taps, drags, flicks, pinch an zoom, and lots of other gestures.